# FourierTransform of a gaussian at -1 and 2

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let

```
ft[w_] := FourierTransform[Exp[-t^2], t, w]
```

Then

```
ft[#] & /@ Range[-2, 3]
```

Evaluates to

```
{1/(Sqrt[2] E), FourierTransform[E^-t^2, t, -1], 
1/Sqrt[2], 1/(Sqrt[2] E^(1/4)),
FourierTransform[E^-t^2, t, 2], 1/(Sqrt[2] E^(9/4))}
```

In other words it fails for -1 and 2, but it's OK for all other integers (I've tried from -100 to 100)
What could be going on? Is there some better way to define the function  ft[w_]?

Comment: Try `ft[w_]=FourierTransform[Exp[-t^2], t, w]` or `ft[w_]:=Evaluate[FourierTransform[Exp[-t^2], t, w]]`

Comment: @Stelios Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Stelios  The problems is not with your function but with `FourierTransform` itself, which does not evaluate for `-1`, `2`, `E`,  and perhaps other numbers.